# How to add a LIKE statement or INDEX function in the IN statemeng using PROC SQL

Tags: sql, sas, sql-like

I use the below code to create an indicator that is 0 if the values in the code are not found in a record of another table and 1 if all pertinant values match a record on another table.

```
proc sql;
create table test as
select id
      ,a.company_yr in (select company_yr from table2) 
                          and a.industry in (select industry from table2)
                          and a.sector in (select sector from table2) as match_ind
from work.table1 a;
quit;
```

My problem is that the company_yr, industry and sector aren't always a perfect match because of abbreviations or other mix ups in the data (e.g., 'FORD MOTORS' in table1 and 'FORD' in table2).  I need some way to use a LIKE statement or INDEX statement in conjunction with a TRIM statement to allow me to match parts of the string to make the indicator more accurate.  I haven't been able to find a way to effectively accomplish this yet.

Comment: The only way to get it right is to clean and normalize your data. Everything else can lead to false matches.

Comment: @SqlZim I wish that was possible, but I can't really do that in my position.  I don't need 100% accuracy, I need around 95%.  That's why I'm looking into a LIKE or INDEX solution.

Comment: The way you wrote the query it looks like you don't care if company_yr, industry, and sector are on the same row in table2, just that each value exists in table2, but maybe on different rows.  Is that what is intended, or do they need to appear on the same row?

Comment: @Talmage they do need to appear on the same row.  Thanks for pointing that out.  When I started writing the code it only had company_yr so I just wanted it to be in the table.  Now I need them to all be on the same row.  I'm not sure exactly how to do that either.

Comment: Then you wouldn't use the IN operator if you want the values to be on the same row.  The EXISTS function would be my choice for a subquery.  A left join would also work with a CASE statement.  My answer uses EXISTS with a subquery.

Comment: Would `LOCATE(A,B) * LOCATE(B,A)>0` be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this where you replace the "strip()" function with whatever you want to accomplish the desired normalization, perhaps with nested "compress()" functions, and some "upcase()" for good fun.  You could turn the equality in the subquery to a LIKE, but it's not clear what you'd match on.

```
proc sql;
create table test as
select
    id,
    exists (select 1 from work.table2 b
            where strip(a.industry) = strip(b.industry)
            and strip(a.sector) = strip(b.sector)
    ) as match_ind
from work.table1 a;
quit;
```